# What is the purpose of positive EBP referencing?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

If the stack grows downwards, and EBP points to the base of the stack then why do I see such operations as `mov eax [ebp + 4]`. Wouldn't this be referencing a variable outside of the current stack frame?

Comment: ebp + offset is used to reference function variables

Comment: What do you mean by function variables? I suppose it depends on the calling convention but my understanding is that parameters are either pushed onto the stack (thus being a negative reference]), or stored in a registry.

Comment: If you ran `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp` before pushing anything else at the start of your function, then `[ebp+4]` will hold the return address pushed by a `call` instruction.  `[ebp + 8]` is the first (non-register) *arg* / parameter.  (not a local variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments get pushed onto the stack before a function is called.

At the start of the function, EBP is pushed as well as any other registers that need to be saved and then EBP is set equal to ESP.

If there are variables declared within the function, such as C automatic variables, ESP is decremented to leave space between EBP and ESP to hold those variables.

So `EBP+offset` is used for arguments and `EBP-offset` is used for local variables.

Before the function returns, ESP is set back to EBP and then the stack is unwound.

Comment: Thank you! I had a misunderstanding as to when EBP was set.

Comment: `ebp-offset` is for local variables, `ebp+offset` is for arguments. (the other way). And esp is decremented (subtracted) to create space for local variables. Stack "grows" downward. The OP actually understands it well in his question, he just didn't realize that "outside" are the values stored to the stack right ahead of calling his code (call arguments). @JacobPersi